# AngularJS: scope(not $scope) of a promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm currently using the $http service from angularjs to retrieve data from locally hosted json file. The data from that file is then sent to a controller and displayed as a state on a view via ui.router, in which the data can be modified. The modified data from that state is then displayed on a different state that shows that data in the json format, to then be copied and pasted into a document by a user. However, every time I change states, the modified data seems to revert back to the original data, seeing that the controller is required to reload the original data each time the state changes. Is there any way I can make the data load only once?

services.js

```
angular.module('angNewsApp')
.service('CustomerService', ['$http', function($http) {

    var customers;


    function init() {
        return $http.get('customers/customers.json')
        .then(function(data) {
            customers = data.data;
        }); 
    }

    function getCustomers() {
        return customers

    }

    return {
        init: init,
        getCustomers: getCustomers
    };

}])
```

customerController.js

```
angular.module('angNewsApp')

.controller('CustomerCtrl', function($scope, CustomerService) {

CustomerService.init().then(function() {
  $scope.customers = CustomerService.getCustomers();
  angular.forEach($scope.customers, function(customer) {
    angular.forEach(customer.external_photos, function(photo) {
      // Possibly fix broken URLs here.
      // photo.external_url
    });
  });
});  
//if you console.log($scope.customers) out here it returns as undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically in this situation I make the http request the first time the service method is called then just use the cached value on subsequent calls.

angular.module('angNewsApp')
.service('CustomerService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

```
function getCustomers() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (!this.customers) {
       $http.get('customers/customers.json')
    .then(function(data) {
        this.customers = data.data;
        deferred.resolve(this.customers);
    });
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(this.customers);
    }

    return deferred.promise;

}

return {
    customers: undefined,
    getCustomers: getCustomers
};
```

}])

Then in your controller
        CustomerService.getCustomers().then(function(customers) {

```
$scope.customers = customers;
...
```

Keep in mind if your want changes to the customers object to persists across states you'll need to update the CustomerService.customers object.